# how to find montly total amount

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

so I have this model two models

```
class Pv(models.Model):
   IA_System_Code = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
   IA_code = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
   Date_recieved = models.DateField()
   Pv_reference = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 120)
   Payee = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   Description = models.CharField(max_length = 500)

   class Meta():
        ordering = ["-IA_System_Code"]

  def __str__(self):
     return self.Pv_reference +" " + self.Description


class staff(models.Model):
  staff_id = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
  rank = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
  amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
  Pv_reference = models.ForeignKey('Pv',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  date_created = models.DateField()
  def __str__(self):
    return  self.name
```

So pv model has a one-to-many relation with staff. It means many staff can benefit from one pv.
And we can have a staff benefiting from different pv's.
So the staff model can have a single staff repeating like 10 times in a month because by benefiting from different pv's .

Now my question is how do I get the monthly total amount of each staff who has been entered in the staff model?

Comment: Do you want the number of staff associated with the Pv?

Comment: no. the staff is always populated as to when a pv is been recorded

Comment: also, show your view.py file

Comment: dont have any view.py code for that yet . now trying to find out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is exactly correct. But this is how we do it.

```
staff.objects.filter(Pv_reference__Date_recieved__gte=FROMDATE, Pv_reference__Date_recieved__lte=TODATE).values('staff_id').aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

Comment: I tried your code and i get this error **'FROMDATE' is not defined**

Comment: No. What I mean is you have to replace FROMDATE and TODATE with your actual dates. Also modify the query according to your need. Chek out this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/